# remotely query text file associated with an instance of vi

Tags: files, process, vi

I have opened several text files (`a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`, ...) in different sessions of `vi` launched from different instances of a `bash` shell. Having then accessed that machine remotely, I wish to determine which session of `vi` is associated with a particular text file (e.g., `a.txt`) and specifically close that session, preferably while saving the current contents of the buffer (as opposed to executing a process `kill`). How can these actions be performed?

Comment: To find out which file is associated with each session, you can try: `file /proc/<pid>/fd/6` This gives you the name of the swap file `vi` is using, which directly tells you which file it's operating on. It's rather hackish and it doesn't help you save buffer contents. I'm hoping a `vi` guru can enlighten us on that matter.

Comment: @JosephR. Wonderful solution to the first half of my question. In my case, the `/proc/<pid>/fd/` folder contains the symlinks `0`, `1`, `2`, and `4`. The first three point to `/dev/pts/3` and the last one points to the swap file. Many thanks.

Comment: My bad. Turns out the extra file-handles on my system were broken symlinks for some reason...
Just goes to show you that this solution isn't so robust.
It can be made robust (e.g. for automation) by running `file` on all the files in the `fd` directory and parsing the output for a line containing ".swp"

Comment: This is turning out to be quite an interesting exercise!
I tried `printf ":wq\n" > /proc/<pid>/fd/0` but no joy! ":wq" appears in the `vi` window but `vi` doesn't seem to respond.

Comment: You could try `GNU screen`. Specifically the `stuff` command can enter text as though it was typed. I expect `tmux` has similar features.

Comment: @JosephR. That is an interesting idea. So you can deliver commands to `vi` but the `\n` newline seems not to register.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully. Thanks for your suggestion. I was reading a little about `screen` after seeing it mentioned in other posts. Can it be applied retroactively to an existing process or must the process be initiated with `screen` in order to take advantage of this facility?

Comment: @user001 It's not that. I don't think that printing to STDIN is the answer. All this seems to do is write stuff to the terminal associated with `vi`. My guess is we have to find the way `vi` communicates with the terminal and send "<Esc>:wq\n" to that particular socket or pipe...

Comment: @user001. Yes you can attach an existing process to a screen session, but I think it usually involves some hairy stuff misusing GDB. Tools exist, e.g [retty](http://pasky.or.cz//dev/retty/), [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) but I haven't tried them.

Answer (score 1):

To see open files, use [lsof(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof).  To control an existing instance of `vim` in order to tell it to save a buffer and quit, you can use its server/client functionality.  See this question for more info on that: [How can I configure vim so that when I send the process a USR1 signal it saves and quits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760014/how-can-i-configure-vim-so-that-when-i-send-the-process-a-usr1-signal-it-saves-a)

Comment: The `vim` server requires X.org to work. I think the use-case here is using `ssh` to access a command line without X.

Comment: As far as I know, using the server client functionality requires `vim` to have been compiled to support it in the first place. This may or may not be the case with the OP. Besides, I think the OP was talking about `vi` not `vim`.